# Separation of Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, separation-of-concerns

I'm creating a b2b application. The application itself is done.
Now i need a public website to inform customers about the product.

The public website and the b2b application might share some data. Since it should be possible to registered and choose a payment plan on the public website and create a user in the b2b application in the same process. So it seems i need to use a shared database.

Is it best to put the public website inside the existing application or is it better to seperate them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, you should separate the two completely and remotely create users through an API in your B2B app.

I actually wrote a blog post on using an API if you want to learn more: http://davidsulc.com/blog/2011/04/17/consuming-a-public-rails-api-with-jquery/

Comment: imo mega-apps should be a code smell. apps should be small, focused, and talk to each other through well defined interfaces

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Divide and conquer, single responsibility, etc. : call it what you want, smaller and simpler apps are easier to develop, manage, and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Service-oriented design might be what you need for this. [This book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321659368) covers the topic.